# "Socket operation on non-socket" error due to strange syntax

Tags: c++, c, g++, cppcheck

I ran across the error `Socket operation on non-socket` in some of my networking code when calling `connect` and spent a lot of time trying to figure out what was causing it.  I finally figured out that the following line of code was causing the problem:

```
if ((sockfd = socket( ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol) < 0)) {
```

See the problem?  Here's what the line should look like:

```
if ((sockfd = socket( ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol)) < 0) {
```

What I don't understand is why the first, incorrect line doesn't produce a warning.  To put it another way, shouldn't the general form:

```
if ( foo = bar() < baz ) do_something();
```

look odd to the compiler, especially running with `g++ -Wall -Wextra`?

If not, shouldn't it at least show up as "bad style" to cppcheck, which I'm also running as part of my compile?

Comment: Pretty much the reason why I *hate* "assignation - conditions"...

Comment: I'm with you on that one, ereOn. 

I also hate the 'comma operator' - I once inadvertently had a comma on the end of an addition split over two physical lines, and it took a while to figure out why I was getting daft results. 

It would be nice if there were #pragmas or compiler options to disable such idioms of C so that we could avoid such problems (and have the error / warning the OP wanted).

Comment: @JTeagle: Definitely, yes. Actually, the reason why the OP didn't get a warning was really a lack of luck. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you don't get any warning because of the double parenthesis `(`.

Try to remove one pair, and you'll get the warning back.

```
#include <iostream>

int foo()
{
    return 2;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
    int l;

    if ((l = foo() < 3)) // Won't generate warning under gcc
    {
    }

    if (l = foo() < 3) // will generate a warning "warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value"
    {
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To avoid such annoying mistakes/typos, I avoid assigning a value and testing it in the same statement. That's too much error prone imho.

Comment: Why do the extra parens make a difference?

Comment: @Robert S. Barnes: I guess this was initialy made to prevent mistakes like writing `if (i = 5)` instead of `if (i == 5)`. If you really want to do `if (i = 5)`, the `gcc` way to remove this warning is to surround the assignation with parenthesis, thus doubling it, as to indicate "this is not a typo, this is **meant** !". Probably not a perfect solution, as your question shows !

Comment: I would think that cppcheck would catch both cases, but surprisingly it doesn't even catch the second case without the extra `()`.

Answer (score 2):

That's one reason why I try not to do too much in one statement. Instead of

```
if ((sockfd = socket( ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol)) < 0) {
```

Why not:

```
sockfd = socket( ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol)
if(sockfd < 0) {
```

Comment: Exactly. It's bad style to put too much in one statement. Also it's also much easier to debug if you put the if on the next line.

Comment: While I might agree with the general statement, "Don't do too much in one statement," I don't know that it applies here.  There is practical value to conciseness in code, and this particular C/C++ idiom has been around for a long time and is basically standard practice.  I've been programming for about 10 years and IIRC this is the first time I've run into this problem.

Comment: I would suggest that any practical value gained by conciseness (kinda curious as to what value you're thinking of) is countered by a drop in readability. If you have to pause on a line or do a double-take just to figure out exactly what effect it has, it's probably better to break it down.